# How to run local host machine script with arguments in a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run a local script in my docker host on a docker container.

I know it is possible to run it using: 
`docker exec -i mycontainer bash < mylocal.sh`, 
but how do I pass arguments to the mylocal.sh using this method.

Say I want to pass the script contents plus an argument like `mylocal.sh argument1`

I don't really want to copy the files over from host to container.

Comment: `I don't really want to copy the files over from host to container.` is there any real reason behind that ? If you need to execute that file from the container, why don't you just make it available there ? I have absolutely no idea how you can pass arguments to that file in the current context (and I even doubt it is possible). If you copy the script to the container (either in the image at build time or with `docker copy...`), then it is as easy as `docker exec -i mycontainer myscript argument1 argument2....`

Comment: @Zeitounator basically I'm coding a tool to run batches on multiple containers in python. The python sdk doesn't have docker cp and if I wanted to volume mount then I would need to do that with all my instances of which I have over 20.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass arguments to bash script using pipe by using -s option.

```
docker exec -i mycontainer bash -s argument1 argument2 < mylocal.sh
```